# JMS Serializer Annotation Group not working on Entity using Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I have been using the Group annotation for years on SF2 and SF3.
I'm trying SF4.1. And I'm getting an empty JSON when I send a GET to my endpoint.

The interesting parts of my composer.json:

```
 "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.3",
 "jms/serializer-bundle": "^2.3",
 "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
 "symfony/serializer-pack": "^1.0"
```

The config:

```
framework:
    serializer:
       enabled: true
       enable_annotations: true

sensio_framework_extra:
    view: { annotations: true }

fos_rest:
   routing_loader:
        default_format: json

   view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'

   format_listener:
        rules:
               - { path: ^/, prefer_extension: true, fallback_format: json, priorities: [ json,xml, html  ] }
```

The Entity

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{

private $id;

/**
 * @Groups({"api"})
 */
private $username;
```

And the endpoint API Controller:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Context\Context;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;

class UserController extends FOSRestController {

public function getUserAction(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $user = $em->getReference('App:User', 1);
    $view = View::create();
    $context = new Context();
    $context->setGroups(['api']);
    $view->setContext($context);
    $view->setData($user);
    return $this->handleView($view);
 }
}
```

If I remove `$context->setGroups(['api']), the JSON has all the User attributes.

Any idea? Thanks!

**Debug Info:**

```
bin/console debug:container jms
```

Select one of the following services to display its information [fos_rest.serializer.jms]:
  [0] fos_rest.serializer.jms

> 0

Information for Service "fos_rest.serializer.jms"
 =================================================

---

Option           Value

---

Service ID       fos_rest.serializer.jms
  Class            FOS\RestBundle\Serializer\JMSSerializerAdapter
  Tags             -
  Public           no
  Synthetic        no
  Lazy             yes
  Shared           yes
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        no
  Autoconfigured   no

---

Comment: Can you try and add the following annotation: `@Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups({"api"})`  to your `$username` field? If it then works you're using the symfony serializer and not JMS.

Comment: You are right :-) And how I can use the JMS serializer?

Comment: I've checked if the `jms_serializer.serializer` service exists, it has preference over the `serializer` service. So it should be the default if the bundle is loaded (check with `bin/console debug:container jms_serializer.serializer` if this is the case). If it is indeed loaded, it seems that the serializer service is overrided (check with `bin/console debug:config fos_rest service.serializer`). If it is you can configure it under the "fos_rest.service.serializer" key and set it to `fos_rest.serializer.jms`.

Comment: I have updated the question including the debug info.  I added the fos_rest.service.serialize: fos_rest.serializer.jms and I'm getting this error:       ServiceNotFoundException
The service "fos_rest.serializer.jms" has a dependency on a non-existent service "jms_serializer.serializer".

Comment: Hmm it seems like the `JMSSerializerBundle` is not loaded since the `jms_serializer.serializer` service does not exist - have you checked that the bundle is loaded?

Comment: Well, I found the jms serializer on vendor folder. What else I need to check?

Comment: Do you have an entry in `config/bundles.php` like `JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle::class => ['all' => true],`? If not try to add it.

Comment: It's now working after adding the service.serializer to the fos_rest.yml and adding the bundle to the bundles.php. Maybe the flex recipe failed. Now I am aware that bundles.php is the SF4 loader of bundles instead of AppKernel. 
 Please answer the question, and I will vote it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue with the following answer? Because I have the same but not resolved by the following answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default FOSRest prefers the JMSSerializer if it is installed. So first check if the service defined by the `JMSSerializerBundle` is defined:

```
./bin/console debug:container jms_serializer.serializer
```

If this command displays an error message (ServiceNotFound) then the bundle is not correctly installed. Check the `config/bundles.php` and add the following line if it's missing:

```
JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

If it actually is installed, you can check the `fos_rest` configuration, if it maybe changes the serializer service. You can configure it like that:

```
fos_rest:   
    service:
        serializer: "fos_rest.serializer.jms"
```